# How do browsers prioritize which @media query to apply if multiple are relevant for the current device?

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a site which needs to have adjusted element positioning based on certain resolutions.

For example, I have this media query:

`@media all and (max-width: 385px)`

And this media query:

`@media all and (max-width: 500px)`

The device in question is **below** 385px wide... but it is prioritizing the 500px media query (which I have for android devices that are between standard iPhone portrait width, and this specific androids portrait width).

See a screenshot of my chrome dev tools here:

http://puu.sh/4oToA.png

It is trying to apply both CSS sets, because it meets the criteria of each, but it priotizes the higher one when I need it to prioritize the lower one.

Answer (score 1):

All of them.

CSS defines specificity rules to figure out what to do if multiple selectors match the same element.
(specifically, the most specific, then bottom-most properties win)

These rules apply whether the selectors are global, in the same media query, or in different media queries.

Answer (score 0):

The order of cascade matters. When applying various @media query blocks for max-width, start with the widest, and work your way down. Rules later in the file will override earlier rules, so in this case, since both apply, you need to set the order properly so that the rules cascade properly. Similarly, if checking for `min-width`, you would start with the smallest sizes and add rules to modify the styles as size goes up. Essentially, the rules for one block apply to both, but the second block, which matches a more specific scenario, will override the first.

If you need the styles to be completely exclusive of each other then you need to set both `min-width` and `max-width` for each @media query block.